# Mostrar texto por defecto cuando un Listview se encuentre vacio

Tags: android, listview

Tengo un `Listview` que obtiene datos de una **BD MySql**. el problema esta cuando la tabla dela BD esta vacía y entro al `activity` donde esta el `Listview`, la aplicación deja de funcionar donde esta vació, alguna idea para poder implementar un texto por defecto o dialogo cuando  este sin datos.

**Asynctask que llena el Listview**

```
public class AsyncRefrescar extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {
ProgressDialog pdLoading = new ProgressDialog(EnviarPregunta.this);
HttpURLConnection conn;
URL url = null;

@Override
protected void onPreExecute() {
    super.onPreExecute();
    pdLoading.setMessage("\tCargando preguntas...");
    pdLoading.setCancelable(false);
    pdLoading.show();

}


@Override
protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
    try {

        url = new URL("http://bdauditorio.esy.es/Verpregunta/mostrarpre.php");

    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
        return e.toString();
    }
    try {


        conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        conn.setReadTimeout(READ_TIMEOUT);
        conn.setConnectTimeout(CONNECTION_TIMEOUT);
        conn.setRequestMethod("GET");


        conn.setDoOutput(true);

    } catch (IOException e1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e1.printStackTrace();
        return e1.toString();
    }

    try {

        int response_code = conn.getResponseCode();


        if (response_code == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {


            InputStream input = conn.getInputStream();
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(input));
            StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
            String line;

            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                result.append(line);
            }


            return (result.toString());

        } else {

            return ("unsuccessful");
        }

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return e.toString();
    } finally {
        conn.disconnect();
    }


}


@Override
protected void onPostExecute(String result) {

    pdLoading.dismiss();
    if (result.equals("unsuccessful")) {
        final AlertDialog.Builder alertaDeError = new AlertDialog.Builder(EnviarPregunta.this);
        alertaDeError.setTitle("Error");
        alertaDeError.setMessage("Ups, no se han podido cargar las preguntas. Intentelo de nuevo.");
        alertaDeError.setPositiveButton("Aceptar", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            }
        });
        alertaDeError.create();
        alertaDeError.show();
    } else {
        //Existen Datos
        List<String> preguntas = new ArrayList<String>();

        //Parsea la respuesta obtenida por el Asynctask
        JSONArray jsonArray = null;
        try {
            jsonArray = new JSONArray(result);
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        assert jsonArray != null;
        for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
            JSONObject preguntaDatos = null;
            try {
                preguntaDatos = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            String pregunta = null;
            try {
                assert preguntaDatos != null;
                pregunta = preguntaDatos.getString("pregunta");
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            preguntas.add(pregunta);
        }
        //crear el Adapter.
        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(EnviarPregunta.this,
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, preguntas);
        //Asignas el Adapter a tu ListView para mostrar los datos.
        mostrarr.setAdapter(adapter);

        ///



    }






}
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes usar el método setEmptyView, tienes que crear una instancia de ListView y otra de una vista, por ejemplo un TextView que diga "Vacío". Ya con ambas instancias puedes usar el método, por ejemplo:

```
ListView lista = findViewById(R.id.lista);
TextView vacio = findViewById(R.id.vacio);
vacio.setText("Vacío");
lista.setEmptyView(vacio);
```

También es importante establecer en XML la siguiente propiedad en tu TextView o en la vista que aparecerá cuando la lista esté vacía:

```
android:visibility="gone"
```

Puedes establecer la vista vacía desde el inicio de la Activity y cuando se obtengan los datos de la lista automáticamente desaparecerá el TextView y aparecerá tu lista.

Comment: Gracias por la idea, lo probaré y votaré pero en este momento no estoy cerca del pc pero si o sí votaré tu respuesta cuando esté en la computadora

Answer (score 0):

El *ListView* si funciona sin elementos, sin embargo deberías tener la cortesía de proveer una lista vacía al *ArrayAdapter* por lo menos. ;)

```
@Override
protected void onPostExecute(String result) {

    // declara la lista aquí
    ArrayList<String> preguntas = new ArrayList<String();
    pdLoading.dismiss();
    if (result.equals("unsuccessful")) {
        // aqui sigue tu código, y aqqui se podría agregar una entrada
        // por defecto a la lista como 
        preguntas.add("vacío");


    } else {
        // Tenemos resultado
        // entonces llenamos la lista
    }
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>
      (EnviarPregunta.this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, preguntas);
    //Asignas el Adapter a tu ListView para mostrar los datos.
    mostrarr.setAdapter(adapter);

    ///



}
```

y tu vista sobrevive.